# Saving "liked" image to local storage

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm having a hard time saving my image that's "liked" into local storage.

I am using the upSplash API and displaying 30 images upon render. The user has the option to "like" an image by clicking on the heart when the image is hovered over. Below is how I determine if the image is liked or not. "allPhotos" hold my 30 images.

```
const toggleLikedImage = (id) => {
    const newArr = allPhotos.map(photo => {
        if(photo.id === id){
            return{
                ...photo,
                liked_by_user: !photo.liked_by_user
            }
        }
       return photo
    })
    setAllPhotos(newArr)
}
```

This function works perfect, and when the image is liked the "heart" icon over the image gets filled in.

Now what I want to do is save the image(s) the are liked into local storage. I tried to do this, and it works but it is only saving one image that is liked into local storage. I created a new piece of state for storage.

```
const [storage, setStorage] = useState([])

    //toggle favorited on and off
const toggleLikedImage = (id) => {
    const newArr = allPhotos.map(photo => {
        if(photo.id === id){
            return{
                ...photo,
                liked_by_user: !photo.liked_by_user
            }
        }
       return photo
    })
    setAllPhotos(newArr)
    
 
 setStorage(newArr.find(image => image.id === id))
 localStorage.setItem("image", JSON.stringify(storage))
}
```

Any idea on how to go about this? Or if there is a better way to do this. I suppose I am setting up local storage in my toggleLikedImage function because here, I already have the image that is getting liked.

Any help would be appreciated, iv been at this for awhile.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't store images in local storage , the reason is local storage only offers 5mb of storage , if you use it for storing images , there are many cases where it might fail , suppose the image is greater than 5 mb , or if the image is partially stored because of memory issue it might get corrupted , use any bucket to store images

Comment: Goutham,
Thanks! I didn't know that, I mainly was just doing it for practice purposes as I've never messed around with local storage before. I'll look into any bucket : )